# Firewall blocks eclipse repository mirrors

Tags: eclipse

I can't install plugins from eclipse because of our corporate firewall, which blocks all jar files. We have already whitelisted eclipse.org and many mirrors, but eclipse.org is redirecting every time to the new mirror.
Is there any way to force eclipse not to use mirrors or use only specific mirrors? Unfotunately it is not possible just to allow jar files because of security policy.

Comment: Does it work if you add `?mirror_id=1` to the update site URL, e. g. `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon?mirror_id=1`?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Still the same issue.

Comment: Be more specific: which `eclipse.org` URL will be redirected to which mirror URL?